# Python, pandas print different output with different methods

Tags: python, pandas, debugging

I'm making a pandas DataFrame out of lists.

```py
@staticmethod
def to_gpd():
   d = [gdt1, gdt2,uav]
   df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'X', 'Y', 'Elevation'])
   print(df)
```

output:

```
    Latitude  Longitude             X             Y     Elevation
0  33.220439  35.808097  3.986139e+06  3.924600e+06           NaN
1  32.959723  35.866616  3.992653e+06  3.889959e+06           NaN
2  33.119654  36.110092  1.900000e+03  4.019757e+06  3.911197e+06
```

lat and lon are good, but x,y, elevation don't match what's in the lists.

but, when I'm debugging and looking in pychram's debugger at the data frame, the data is correct.
[image: debug output]
Also, when I'm using iloc, it does print the right float.

```py
print(df.iloc[0][2])

output: 3986139.124316147
```

Comment: That is not an integer, it's a float. And the values in the df do match the correct values, it's just in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation)

Comment: @roganjosh how can I print in float and not scientific notation?

Comment: That's something you can easily search for now you know what's happening